# HERE Maps Android: Calculate Directions While Avoiding Specific Areas

Tags: java, android, here-api

I'm working on a project using Here Maps API for Android that includes calculating directions that avoid specific areas (mainly just intersections). I see that it can be done in Javascript [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/example-route-avoiding-an-area.html), so I was just wondering if it can be done in Android. Looking through the Route and Routeoptions in the documentation doesn't seem to yield anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Please mention what did you tried so that it's easier for the people to understand better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this can be done in our Android Premium SDK. You can use the `addBannedArea` to the `coreRouter` before calling `calculateRoute`. Check out the `DynamicPenalty` class:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/routing.html
https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/index.html

Comment: Aah okay, I missed the DynamicPenalty class, thank you!